# Updating kendo library ffrom 2013 to latest

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Have a look at the bubbles that are placed on the first data point of X-axis.
This is how it looks with the latest version(half cut first bubbles, and even last but there are no data points).[image]

Here is how it looked in the older vaersion that is of 2013.
[image]

With the updated version I observe they show half bubble for data plotted on start and end of X-axis. I have a fixed range graph.

**PS:** I have commercial licence of kendo ui. I had to update because in version 2013 the date timepicker widget had bug in getting the dateand time using min function, which apparently is solved in later version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your chart configuration:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    panes: [{
        clip: false
    }],
    ...
});
```

Documentation about this chart property could be find here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-panes.clip